# how to convert udf file to docx via command line

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell, conversion, vbscript

How can I convert a udf file to docx using the command line? Is there a program that does this? This command line can be PowerShell or VBScript.

Here is the file:
[image]

Here is a link to the editor:
https://uyap.gov.tr/UYAP-Editor

Comment: The editor scanned clean with Defender and VirusTotal, but I'm installing it in a VM just to safe. The installer is in Turkish, so that's a bit challenging for me. The UDF document extension appears to be unique to this application. Hopefully, it's actually something common like XML, PDF or RTF underneath.

Comment: The UDF file is actually a ZIP file containing an XML file. Word DOCX files are also XML files in a ZIP wrapper, but the UDF format does not appear to be the same as DOCX.

Answer (score 2):

The `Uyap Doküman Editörü` app, by default, saves files with a UDF extension. The file is actually a ZIP file containing a single file named `content.xml` which is the actual document contents, plus all of its formatting.

The only identifier in the XML file is `template format_id="1.8"`. It appears that this XML format is unique to the app. The app's programmer could probably very easily add an option to save in docx format or RTF format. But I think it would be very difficult for anyone else to write a script to convert the format.

The app itself provides the option to save in PDF format, which is universal and can be read directly by Microsoft Word 2013 or higher. That appears to be your best conversion option.

Comment: Well sir, can content.xml file be converted to docx?

Comment: You would need to get the specifications for `template format_id="1.8"` from the `Uyap Doküman Editörü` author or spend a lot of time reverse engineering the format.

Comment: I understood thank you